# How to open a bootstrap modal from antoher page html?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have already finished the code on the page by the way mysite.ru / jqueryform-75cb32 / form.html
How to make it open in the modal window at mysite.ru/report.html on the button

```html
<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm pull-right act_popup_dota" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_dota2">
     Leave a vacancy
</a>
```

https://pastebin.com/5z0y8yBg

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#modal_dota2').on('shown.bs.modal',function(){ //correct here use 'shown.bs.modal' event which comes in bootstrap3
   $(this).find('iframe').attr('src','http://mysite.ru/jqueryform-75cb32/form.htm');
})
```

Comment: You must set max-width or width to the iframe within the modal.

Comment: Could you please write as

Comment: Can you put the code of the page you're calling the modal in to the https://pastebin.com/ ?